# Unable to connect to the AWS RDS database from ASP.NET Hangfire

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-rds, hangfire

I am developing an ASP.NET Core Web API project. In my project, I am using Hangfire to run the background task. Therefore, I am configuring the Hangfire to use the database like this.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
          {
        services.AddHangfire(configuration =>
                 {
                    configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("Server=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Integrated Security=true;");
                 });
      //
    }

In the above code, I am using Local DB. Now, I am trying to use AWS RDS database since I am deploying my application on the AWS Elastic Beanstalks. I created a function for getting the connection



public static string GetRDSConnectionString()
      {

         string dbname = "ebdb";

         if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(dbname)) return null;

         string username = "admin";
         string password = "password";
         string hostname = "cxcxcxcx.xcxcxcxc.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:1234";
         string port = "1234";

         return "Data Source=" + hostname + ";Initial Catalog=" + dbname + ";User ID=" + username + ";Password=" + password + ";";
      }
```

I got the above code from the official AWS documentation. In the above code, what I am not clear is the database name, is the database name always be "ebdb"? I tried to find out the database name. But could not. In the tutorial, it is saying to use ebdb. So, I used it.

Then in configuration, I changed to this.

```
configuration.UseSqlServerStorage(AppConfig.GetRDSConnectionString());
```

When I run the code, it is giving me this error.

```
Win32Exception: The parameter is incorrect
Unknown location

SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, object providerInfo, bool redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, bool applyTransientFaultHandling)

Win32Exception: The parameter is incorrect
```

Basically, it cannot connect to the database when I run my application. But I set the correct credentials. the only thing I double is the database name (ebdb). What is wrong with my configuration and what is wrong? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Calling a few things out here just incase...

You have your port specified both in your `host` variable and as a separate `port` variable...but never use `port`.

Can you confirm that you are able to access your SQLServer via another means, such as from SQL Management Studio?

RDS uses SSL by default now for connections, my .NET is rusty but would you need to inform the connection string that it needs to run over a secure protocol?

& finally, regarding the AWS Security Group on your RDS instance. Have you opened up the correct port to your machine/network/IP?

This is the screenshot of the RDS db instance security group section in the console.

[image]

Comment: I tried to connect to the db from SSMs entering the Endpoint for the server. I could not connect.

Comment: then it might be worth checking the security group of the RDS instance to see if you are being blocked

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the security section in the question. Can u check, please?

Comment: Yes, it suggests that the only allowed ingress traffic is from security group with id: sg-0736a66c. Take a look at that group and see what access it allows